# Concatenating JSON key, value pairs into string

Tags: jmespath

I have a simple JSON object that may have the following structure:

```json
{
  "data":{
     "k1":"v1",
     "k2":"v2"
  }
}
```

The object can contain any number of key-value pairs, but it will always be flat, meaning there are no nested objects. I'm looking to construct a string in the format of **`"k1:v1:k2:v2"`** using JMESPath. Is it possible to achieve this using JMESPath?

I was trying to use
`[data.keys(@),data.values(@)].join(':',[])`
But this results in:
`"k1:k2:v1:v2"`

Comment: You'd need to be able to zip the two arrays (of keys and values) together in order to do this, which is not an existing functionality, unfortunately.

Comment: So it is impossible to do with just jmespath?